# How to GROUP BY a Subquery value returned by a CASE statement

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, group-by, subquery

I have been battling to find an answer for this. It is code that I maintain and has no errors. It is inside a stored procedure that returns data for a report.

I have made it smaller for readability and just included the essential parts.

It works with no error but a request has been made to make it group all related data in the respective rows.

Main issue is applying the GROUP BY statement for the third CASE statement which contains a SUBQUERY:

```
    SELECT
            CompanyName,
            CompanyRef,
            Amount,
            Reference,
            VendorNo,
            CASE ErrorID WHEN 10 'Company Name: ' + CompanyName + 'CompanyRef' END AS InvalidCompanyNameForRef,
            CASE ErrorID WHEN 11 'Vendor Number:' + VendorNo END AS InvalidVendorNo,
            CASE ErrorID WHEN 12 (SELECT TOP(1) 'Non VAT Amount:' + CAST(PendingPayments.NonVatAmount AS varchar) + 'Import Amount:' + CAST(Imported.PaymentAmount) FROM PendingPayments
                        WHERE  Imported.CompanyRef = PendingPayments.CompanyRef
                           AND Imported.VendorNo = PendingPayments.VendorNo
                               AND ISNUMERIC(Imported.PaymentAmount) = 1
                           AND CAST(Imported.PaymentAmount AS MONEY) <> PendingPayments.NonVatAmount AND PendingPayments.isVAT = 0      
                         ) END As PaymentAmountMismatch
        .
        .
        .
GROUP BY
            CompanyName,
            CompanyRef,
            Amount,
            Reference,
            VendorNo,
            CASE ErrorID WHEN 10 'Company Name: ' + CompanyName + 'CompanyRef' END,
            CASE ErrorID WHEN 11 'Vendor Number:' + VendorNo END
```

How do I make it group by the field derived from the SUBQUERY.

Instead of returning different rows for different columns of the same data, I would like it to return something like this:

```
CompanyName | CompanyRef | Amount | Reference | VendorNo | InvalidCompanyNameForRef     | Invalid Vendor Number | PaymentAmountMismatch
------------+------------+--------+-----------+----------+------------------------------+-----------------------+-----------------------------------------+
ABC         | 1          | 25.00  | INV001    |390       |Company Name: ABC CompanyRef:1|                       |   
DEF         | 5          | 12.00  | INV002    |212       |                              |                   212 |Expected Amount:12.50, Import Amount:12.00
HIJ         | 7          | 9.50   | INV003    |31        |Company Name: HIJ CompanyRef:7|                       |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me, [CTE can help you](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx). Code do not tested, but I think it's enough to get idea.

```
    WITH cte 
           (CompanyName,
            CompanyRef,
            Amount,
            Reference,
            VendorNo,
            InvalidCompanyNameForRef,
            InvalidVendorNo,
            PaymentAmountMismatch) AS
(
SELECT
CompanyName,
CompanyRef,
Amount,
Reference,
VendorNo,
CASE ErrorID WHEN 10 'Company Name: ' + CompanyName + 'CompanyRef' END AS InvalidCompanyNameForRef,
CASE ErrorID WHEN 11 'Vendor Number:' + VendorNo END AS InvalidVendorNo,
CASE ErrorID WHEN 12 (SELECT TOP(1) 'Non VAT Amount:' + CAST(PendingPayments.NonVatAmount AS varchar) + 'Import Amount:' + CAST(Imported.PaymentAmount) FROM PendingPayments
            WHERE  Imported.CompanyRef = PendingPayments.CompanyRef
                AND Imported.VendorNo = PendingPayments.VendorNo
                    AND ISNUMERIC(Imported.PaymentAmount) = 1
                AND CAST(Imported.PaymentAmount AS MONEY) <> PendingPayments.NonVatAmount AND PendingPayments.isVAT = 0      
                ) END As PaymentAmountMismatch
)
SELECT * FROM cte 
GROUP BY
    CompanyName,
    CompanyRef,
    Amount,
    Reference,
    VendorNo,
    InvalidCompanyNameForRef,
    InvalidVendorNo,
    PaymentAmountMismatch
```